# Is RTCDataChannel send() a synchronous/blocking call?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, file-transfer, rtcdatachannel

I'm trying to send a file in chunks over WebRTC, and I'm wondering if I can create a callback function to be called after `RTCDataChannel.send()` finishes sending each chunk of the file.

Is `RTCDataChannel.send()` a synchronous/blocking call? If so, my callback can be executed on the line after `.send()`.

If `.send()` is asynchronous/non-blocking, then this will get tricky since it doesn't seem like `.send()` accepts a callback function, and I want to avoid using a buffer and a timeout.

Comment: If it's synchronous, you don't *need* a callback?

Comment: well... I have an abstraction around `.send()`, so I'd have to pass in a callback to a function I've defined that calls `.send()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`send` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-datachannel-send) is blocking. It however doesn't wait until the data went over the wire, but only puts the data on an internal buffer from where it might later (or in parallel to the script execution) be sent.

The amount of data that has not been transmitted is available as the [`bufferedAmount` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-datachannel-bufferedamount), which will be synchronously increased by every `send()` call (and not be updated otherwise until the next event loop turn).

You might make your wrapper asynchronous therefore, and put a timeout before actually calling `send()` when the currently buffered data is "too much" (by whatever criterion you see fit).

Comment: thanks Bergi! good to know that `.send()` is blocking, and good to know that `bufferedAmount` exists. sounds like I'll have to poll on `bufferedAmount` and wait until it is "small enough"

Answer (score 1):

As noted above send() is effectively async - you don't get delivery receipt. 
However there is a callback `onbufferedamountlow` which is invoked when
the channel drains it's send buffer below a value set with `bufferedAmountLowThreshold` 
(see [MDN onbufferedamountlow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel/onbufferedamountlow))

You can use that callback to decide when to send the next chunk.

Note however that this is relatively new to the draft standard and may not be supported everywhere.